# AnythingSlider with dynamic height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, anythingslider

I am using [anythingslider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/) and have a problem.

My content elements get loaded from a CMS and their height can vary. I would like to set the slider height to the height of the tallest element, but this doesn't seem to work.

I tried it like this:

```
var max_height = 0;
$(".canythingslider .ccontentelement").each(function() {
    var h = $(this).height();
    if(h > max_height) {max_height = h;}
});
$(".canythingslider").css("height", max_height + "px");
$(".canythingslider").anythingSlider();
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work now. The resizeContents option of AnythingSlider has to be set to false, then the above script does what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (CMS is TYPO3, I try to make a slider with ext. gridelements).
For me, this solution works better:

```
var max_height = 0;
$(".anythingslider .contentelement").each(function() {
    var h = $(this).height();
    if(h > max_height) {max_height = h;}
});
$(".anythingslider-outer").css("height", max_height + "px");
$(".anythingslider").anythingSlider(
    'expand': true
);
```

What I did is: Wrap a div around the anythingslider:

```
<div class="anythingslider-outer">
    <ul class="anythingslider">...</ul>
</div>
```

This outer container gets the height, the width now is also flexible. Anythingslider is stretched to the dimensions of this container (with expand=true).

**Even better is this JavaScript solution**, which handles several sliders on one page (not only one slider):

```
$("ul.anythingslider").each(function(){
    var anythingsliderContainer = $(this).closest(".anythingslider-outer");
    anythingsliderContainer.css("height", 0);
    anythingsliderContainer.find("ul.anythingslider > li").each(function(){
        if($(this).height() > anythingsliderContainer.height()){
            anythingsliderContainer.css("height", $(this).height());
        }
    });
});

$('ul.anythingslider').anythingSlider({
    'expand': true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if this is helpful please let me know.

`function heightLeveler(group) {

```
    var tallest = 0;

    group.each(function () {
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if (thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}
```

`heightLeveler(".canythingslider");`

Comment: No, it doesn't help. But thanks anyway.
My code sets the height correctly but it seems like AnythingSlider ignores the height if I set it this way. If the height gets set in the CSS file then it works but i need to set it dynamically.
This is weird!